# Prove Tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can you please prove the equation (~pVr)^(pVq)->(qVr) without using truth table.
I have tried and ended up half way
~[(~pVr)^(pVq)]V(qVr)
~(~pVr)V~(pVq)V(qVr)
(p^~r)V(~p^~q)VqVr
(p^~r)VrV(~p^~q)Vq

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It's not an equation.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the meaning of this formula. Using using $A\lor B\equiv \neg A\to B$, rewriting the formula in terms of implication yields this equivalent formula: 
$$
((\neg q \to p) \land (p\to r))\to(\neg q\to r).
$$
Because $(A\land B)\to C \equiv A\to(B\to C)$, the above formula is  equivalent to 
$$
(\neg q \to p) \to ((p\to r)\to(\neg q\to r)).
$$
The last formula is an instance of one of the *axioms* of many Hilbert-style deductive systems for propositional logic. It's a well-known tautology.